# Mongo shell keep passing document into default database "test". Eventhough I've already set to another database

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I've set mongo database to current database using `use currentdb`.
When inserting data from local host. The data keeps entering into default database "test".

Comment: can you share query or command which you are using to insert?

Comment: This is example you can use to import from csv `mongoimport -d DB_NAME -c COLLECTION_NAME --type csv --file PATH/FILE.csv`

Comment: @ROHITKHURANA I'd execute `use currentdb` . and then run a query api via localhost to insert data. Yet the data will still be inserted to "test" db instead of "currentdb". for the query, it was just a '.save' query, to save data into db

Comment: you can find **.mongorc.js** file in you home directory. You can change default db name there by **db = db.getSiblingDB("databasename")** then try or you can connect mongodb by dbname like **mongo databasename**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `use <databasename>` in the shell affects only the current session.

If you then connect with node.js/mongoose and use .save(), that will be a separate session.

To find out the database being used by a mongoose connection, check the [name](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#connection_Connection-name) property.

To set the database name when [connecting](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-connect), specify the name in the URL like:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:pass@localhost:port/database');
```